# Two-way fixed effects and collinearity

Tags: multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model

I am modeling the relationship of an independent variable $(x_t/z_i),$ where $t$ indexes time and $i$ individual with an outcome $y_{it}$. The log transformation of $(x_t/z_i)$ is prohibitively collinear with fixed effects $(D_t,D_i)$ but neither of $D_t$ nor $D_i$ individually. The untransformed $(x_t/z_i)$ is *not* collinear with $(D_t,D_i)$, $D_t$, or $D_i$.

(1) $\qquad y_{it} = \alpha + \beta(x_t/z_i) + D_t + D_i +
    \varepsilon_{it}$
      (2) $\qquad y_{it} = a + \beta \ln(x_t/z_i) + D_t
    + D_i + \varepsilon_{it}$

What’s happening here? Is model (1) plausible?

Some values, as requested in comments.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Could you share a small subset of the untransformed covariate?

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasBilach. I'm quite sure what you are asking for. Would you like to see table of values?

Comment: Yes. I would like to see the untransformed data values.

Comment: @ThomasBilach, I've added some values to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Reproducing the OP's panel
# N = 4
# T = 2
# 8 unit-time observations

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(plm)

set.seed(2021)

df <- tibble(
  unit = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
  time = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  y = runif(8, 0, 1),
  x = c(9454.5, 9368.55, 9454.5, 9368.55, 9454.5, 9368.55, 9454.5, 9368.55),
  z = c(11175.81, 11175.81, 8590.219, 8590.219, 11175.81, 11175.81, 8590.219, 8590.219),
  raw_xz = x / z,
  log_xz = log(x / z)
  )
```

It appears your model is estimable, so long as you drop the time fixed effects.

Assuming you acquired a panel with only two time periods, then your two-way fixed effects (TWFE) equation should produce results equivalent to a *first difference* (FD) model. Once we difference your covariate of interest *across time*, it is more obvious why your model is inestimable. For instance, your *differenced* raw covariate $\frac{x_t}{z_i}$ shows variation across units, whereas differencing $\ln(\frac{x_t}{z_i})$ results in the exact same change over time, resulting in no variation across units. Software should warn you when it cannot estimate a variance.

Let's see if I can demonstrate this using some sample data:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 7
   unit  time     y     x      z raw_xz  log_xz
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     1 0.451 9454. 11176.  0.846 -0.167 
2     1     2 0.784 9369. 11176.  0.838 -0.176 
3     2     1 0.710 9454.  8590.  1.10   0.0959
4     2     2 0.382 9369.  8590.  1.09   0.0867
5     3     1 0.636 9454. 11176.  0.846 -0.167 
6     3     2 0.701 9369. 11176.  0.838 -0.176 
7     4     1 0.640 9454.  8590.  1.10   0.0959
8     4     2 0.267 9369.  8590.  1.09   0.0867
```

The foregoing panel dataset observes four cross-sectional units ($N = 4$) over two time periods ($T = 2$). I simulated some $y$ values to approximate the subset of numerical quantities presented. Everything else is similar to the data values you presented.

```
# Comparing a TWFE vs. FD (T = 2)

mod_lm <- lm(y ~ raw_xz + as.factor(unit) + as.factor(time), data = df)  # two-way fixed effects (T = 2)
mod_plm <- plm(y ~ raw_xz, model = "fd", data = df)                      # first difference (T = 2)

mod_lm$coefficients['raw_xz']
  raw_xz 
237.4307

mod_plm$coefficients['raw_xz']
  raw_xz 
237.4307
```

As indicated above, your two models produce equivalent estimates of the untransformed covariate. But what variation is left over once you difference your model?

Let's run a couple of FD estimators comparing $\frac{x_t}{z_i}$ with $\ln(\frac{x_t}{z_i})$:

```
# Note: FD models estimated using the plm() function
# model = "fd"

plm_raw <- plm(y ~ raw_xz, model = "fd", data = df)
plm_log <- plm(y ~ log_xz, model = "fd", data = df)
 
plm_raw$coefficients['raw_xz']
  raw_xz 
237.4307 
plm_log$coefficients['log_xz']
<NA> 
  NA
```

Software cannot estimate a variance. As a consequence, `log_xz` must be dropped.

Oftentimes a simulation isn't necessary. Instead, we can look at the data frame and see what redundancies exist, if any. Let's difference the periods and see what variation we can exploit. Here is the *differenced* data frame:

```
df %>%
  group_by(unit) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(y:log_xz), list(~ .x - lag(.x))
  )

# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   unit [4]
   unit  time       y     x     z   raw_xz   log_xz
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1     1 NA       NA      NA NA       NA      
2     1     2  0.333  -86.0     0 -0.00769 -0.00913
3     2     1 NA       NA      NA NA       NA      
4     2     2 -0.328  -86.0     0 -0.0100  -0.00913
5     3     1 NA       NA      NA NA       NA      
6     3     2  0.0650 -86.0     0 -0.00769 -0.00913
7     4     1 NA       NA      NA NA       NA      
8     4     2 -0.374  -86.0     0 -0.0100  -0.00913
```

Note what $\ln(\frac{x_t}{z_i})$ does to your data values in the last column. Each unit undergoes the exact same change across time. Software *should* produce a warning(s) (e.g., `cor(y, haty): the standard deviation is zero`).

---

**See Comments**

In response to your comments, it appears you observe multiple units over *more than* two time periods. I erroneously assumed your truncated dataset preserved the size of $T$. My answer is still useful, assuming each $i$ has the same pattern.

The variable $x_t$ is unit-invariant. Normalizing by $z_i$, which is time-invariant, is valid. However, log-transforming this quotient produces values where each $i$ undergoes the same change from period-to-period. By the properties of logarithms: $\ln(\frac{x_t}{z_i}) = \ln(x_t) - \ln(z_i)$. Put more simply, each $x_t$-value is centered around $z_i$, where each $i$ now experiences the same deviation across time periods. Here is some sample data in tabular form where $N = 3$ and $T = 3$:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
unit & time & x_t & z_i & \ln(x_t) - \ln(z_i) \\
\hline
 1 & 1 & 9,454 & 11,176 & -0.17 \\
 1 & 2 & 9,369 & 11,176 & -0.18 \\
 1 & 3 & 6,419 & 11,176 & -0.55 \\
\hline
 2 & 1 & 9,454 & 23,190 & -0.90 \\
 2 & 2 & 9,369 & 23,190 & -0.91 \\
 2 & 3 & 6,419 & 23,190 & -1.28 \\
\hline
 3 & 1 & 9,454 & 62,176 & -1.88 \\
 3 & 2 & 9,369 & 62,176 & -1.89 \\
 3 & 3 & 6,419 & 62,176 & -2.27 \\
\end{array}
$$

Note, the within-unit change is the same for all $i$ as you move from period-to-period. Software will invariably drop a time period to achieve something estimable. According to my example, which is based upon your sample data, you can estimate individual-specific intercepts.

It will be difficult to reproduce the collinearity without seeing your data. In my estimation, it appears each shift in $\ln(\frac{x_t}{z_i})$ over the time periods is the same for all persons in your sample. Suppose your covariate is some intensity measure (i.e., treatment), then you can think about this as each unit receiving a similar dosage over time.

Discretized measures produce the same problem. Suppose some discrete jump in $x_t$ is observed. By construction, if $x$ is $t$-subscripted, then the change is the same for *all units*. The only way to avoid collinearity is if some individuals receive the shock (i.e., treatment) and others do not; discrete shocks experienced by all $i$ and in the same periods $t$ will be collinear with the time fixed effects.

In either case, any panel data estimator run in either R or Stata should balk. You might be receiving the unhelpful `empty model` message in your output. In particular, software is warning you that once you condition on unit *and* time fixed effects, you have nothing left over to exploit.

Comment: thanks so much for your help! I wasn't quite sure what you were after. I have a balanced panel with 7 time periods and 58 individuals. As you mention, the model runs if I drop the time FE works. Alternatively, the model runs if I drop the individual FE. The issue seems to be that the variance of ln(x_t/z_i) is constant across both time and individual, but not so for (x_t/z_i).

Comment: Does the lack of variance that I demonstrated above generalize to your setting? I assume your covariate of interest drops out of the model once you condition on unit and time fixed effects. If possible, show me a subset of values for two individuals over all 7 periods and I will adjust my answer.

Comment: Or more simply, does each individual experience the same deterministic change over time, like it does in your post?

Comment: I lost track of this question, @thomas, but wanted to thank you. the log transformation explanation nailed it for me. Thaks!